# Access to elements in a list of list (Rccp)

Tags: rcpp

I created a list of list in Rcpp (replicated 3 times)

```
cppFunction('List myfunction(){
List L = rep(List::create(List::create(Named("elmement_1")=1,Named("elmement_2")=4)),3);
return L;
}')
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$elmement_1
[1] 1

[[1]]$elmement_2
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]]$elmement_1
[1] 1

[[2]]$elmement_2
[1] 4


[[3]]
[[3]]$elmement_1
[1] 1

[[3]]$elmement_2
[1] 4
```

Then, how I can access to each element (list) of L and each element inside theses elements ?

I would be very grateful if anyone can help

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you edit your question and make it more clear what it is that you desire to do but cannot, and maybe detail "why not"?  Looks like you aim to create and export a nested list and have done so.  Otherwise, maybe consult existing examples --- over 2000 Rcpp questions, over 100 posts at the Rcpp Gallery site and even packages like RcppExamples on CRAN which has List examples.

Comment: You access the elements in a list using `[`. For example, if you _know_ each list element is also list (as per your example), you would do `Rcpp::List l1 = L[0]` for the first element.